# Why does Oracle return no results for a specific query, unless FETCH FIRST is specified?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

Given the following Oracle queries, the first query returns 0 results on our Oracle 19c database, but the second query returns a list of hundreds of results. Does anyone understand why `FETCH FIRST` would return results, but without `FETCH FIRST` no results are returned? We've been able to reproduce this across multiple Oracle 19c instances. Practically it is alright for me to add `FETCH FIRST` in our code but I do not understand the technical implications.

Query with no results:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table_s s
    JOIN table_r r ON r.person_id = s.person_id
                      OR r.person_id = s.partner_id
    JOIN table_p p ON p.person_id = r.person_id
WHERE
    p.type = 'NP'
    AND p.value LIKE 'TOM%'
    AND p.category = 'NAME';
```

Query with results:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table_s s
    JOIN table_r r ON r.person_id = s.person_id
                      OR r.person_id = s.partner_id
    JOIN table_p p ON p.person_id = r.person_id
WHERE
    p.type = 'NP'
    AND p.value LIKE 'TOM%'
    AND p.category = 'NAME'
FETCH FIRST 20000000 ROWS ONLY;
```

`person_id` is always a `NUMBER(19, 0)`, and the other columns `type`, `value` and `category` are all `VARCHAR2` with different numbers of bytes.

Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements that would let us replicate the problem and the exact version of your database. I cannot replicate the problem on [Oracle 18](https://dbfiddle.uk/UY_aO-YO), [Oracle 21](https://dbfiddle.uk/ShiBHAFb) or [Oracle 23](https://dbfiddle.uk/zf481s4U) (but db<>fiddle does not have an Oracle 19 instance).

Comment: This is not possible. Check for typos in the query that doesn't work.

Comment: Option 1: You have encountered a very weird bug in Oracle where the first query is returning incorrect results.  That seems very unlikely with such a simple query but maybe your actual query is more complicated with a bunch of views rather than tables.  You'd need to generate a query plan to try to debug where the optimizer is going wrong and probably work with Oracle support to see if there is a patch that fixes the bug you have encountered.  Option 2: You are mistaken and the two queries are not actually identical save for the `FETCH` clause.

Comment: Do you have any virtual private database (VPD) or similar policies which are bypassed by adding `fetch first`? SQL translation framework profiles? Stale materialized views which the query is rewritten to use? As Justin says, look at the query plans to see if there's anything in the first not in the second query